# acessing $_POST variables after an ajax form submit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am submitting a form using AJAX (jQuery) to a PHP script.

Here is the JavaScript:

```
// Validate form fields
$(function () {
    //Check to see if email is not empty
    if (email == "") {
        $("label#email_error").show();
        $("input#email").focus();
        return false;
    }

    var dataString = 'firstname=' + firstname + '&email=' + email + '&lastname=' + lastname;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/",
        data: dataString,
        success: function () {
            var counter = <?php echo($counter['count'] + 1); ?>

            counter = numberWithCommas(counter);

            $('#counter').html(counter);
            $('#contact_form').html("<div id='message'></div>").fadeIn(1500, function () {
                $('#message').html("<h2>Thanks " + (firstname) + "!</h2>").append("<p>We will be in touch soon.</p>");
            });
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Within the PHP script I have this code:

```
if (!empty($_POST)){        
    $adestra = $this->adestraAction('contact.create' , array('1', array('1.email' =>  $_POST['email'] , '1.forename' => $_POST['firstname'] , '1.surname' => $_POST['lastname'],'1.source' => 'signupbox' )));
    $add = $this->addToListAction($adestra, $magazineID);
}
```

The $_POST varibles do not seem to be getting set. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Can you post the ajax query? Or in your php file if you print the post variable what do you get? <?php print_r($_POST);?>

Comment: can you post jquery code too? maybe it is doing a GET request but even if not, seeing the code will help

Comment: when I print the $_POST nothing is echoed out.  Im not sure that I have acsess to $_POST becuse it is a server variable

Comment: thats only the success function. post ALL the code of the $.ajax(...) call

Comment: You're using data: `dataString: dataString`. I doubt that's what you intend to work.

Comment: And how is the dataString variable populated? That should contain all the data you have to post, does it?

Comment: Side note: You should really end each line in JavaScript with a `;` (even though they are not required).

Answer (score 2):

```
data: dataString : dataString,
```

This is a syntax error.  I assume you really want:

```
data: dataString,
```

Comment: Please read the post again.  I have added a bit more code to give you a bit more info.  What im basically trying to find out is if the $_POST variables will be getting set if the form is submitted via ajax as they are server variables.

Comment: @richelliot: What do you mean by "server variables"?  Your code looks like it should work.  Does `$_POST` get filled correctly?

Comment: when i talk about 'server variables' im taking about $_POST. sorry for the confusion!  $_POST never seems to get populated.

Answer (score 1):

Data in the jQuery POST request has to be a Javascript object.

Change it to:

```
data: {
   'key' : 'value'
}
```

Alternatively, if dataString is already formatted as a querystring, see Rocket's answer.

Comment: `data` can also be a query string `data: 'key=value&key2=value2'`.

Comment: I'm too quick. :-P  I see that now :-)

Comment: Ok, i tired to change the post request to a javascript object but still no jooy.  I am working within a wordpress wiget...not sure if that would affect anything?

Answer (score 0):

Please debug/alert dataString after this line

```
var dataString = 'firstname=' + firstname + '&email=' + email + '&lastname=' .....
```

to see whether all the values are being correctly populated? that might be the issue

Comment: Ok I found out what the problem was.  My DEV enviroment wasnt setup properly so it was posting the data to the index page!